# A significant milestone

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My left half is often used in dividing money,
It's not round but square: hold Attila in fear!

My right half is often used in metric spaces,
Islands in borderlands, lakes in a state.

Together with and we're sweet,
Together without we're this post.

Comment: I knocked this up in just a few minutes - hopefully it's not too bad.

Comment: Trying not to spoiler too much - How did you know when you were making the post that this would work?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 That's why I had to do it in just a few minutes, per my comment above. I realised suddenly that we were approaching that point, and rushed to make a fitting puzzle. Luckily I succeeded in time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are:

> **100,000** (one hundred thousand)

*My left half is often used in dividing money,*

> Many world currencies are divided into 100 (**one hundred**) smaller units (e.g. cents in a dollar, pence in a pound).

*It's not round but square: hold Attila in fear!*

> 100 is a *square* number (10x10). 'Hundred' sounds like 'Hun-dread' ([Attila the Hun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attila), dread = fear).

*My right half is often used in metric spaces,*

> *One thousand* is often used in metric system measurements (e.g. 1000 grams in a kilogram; 1000 metres in a kilometre; 1000 millilitres in a litre).

*Islands in borderlands, lakes in a state.*

> The [Thousand Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousand_Islands) are on the US-Canada border; the nation state of Finland is known as the [Land of a Thousand Lakes](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/why-is-finland-called-a-land-of-a-thousand-lakes.html).

*Together with and we're sweet,*

> **[Hundreds and thousands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonpareils)** ('hundreds' and 'thousands' with 'and') are a sweet ice cream and confectionery topping.

*Together without we're this post.*

> And this question is apparently post* number 100,000 ('hundred' and 'thousand' *without* 'and') on PSE - a significant milestone indeed (check the URL!).
>
>  <sub>NB 'Posts' on SE network sites include questions, answers, tag wikis, and the other various components that make up site content. We're still some way off the 100,000<sup>th</sup> question!</sub>

Comment: Ooooh congrats to the site! :)

Comment: Also, rot13(uhaqerq tenaq vf n pnaql one) though that doesn't necessarily work with the "and"

Comment: Yep, you got it. A couple of corrections: I meant "state" as in "nation" (figure out which one); and post IDs also count tag wikis and other things, so we don't even have that many Q&A yet.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Noted, and corrected! :)